# Failed unit test. @angular/cli + pug

Tags: angular, webpack, karma-runner

I executed `$ ng eject`.
And, I added pug-html-loader to webpack.config.js

`$ yarn start` works fine, but `$ yarn test` raises the following error.

```
karma start ./karma.conf.js

ERROR in ./src/app/app.component.pug
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:3)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| h1 Welcome to {{title}}!
|
 @ ./src/app/app.component.ts 17:22-52
 @ ./src/app/app.component.spec.ts
 @ ./src \.spec\.ts$
 @ ./src/test.ts
```

webpack.config.js
https://gist.github.com/Ghostrick/918de6989d6c8717a0e16b3bfd44a522

Help me!

Comment: Post your webpack config.

Comment: @LazarLjubenović I added a link of gist.